# Visual studio - how to catch debug (break) after show message box

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have a situation like this. In my code, there are countless code blocks like this.

```
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
catch( Ogre::Exception& e )//Yes, I'm using Ogre, but you get the idea :)
{
    MessageBoxA( NULL, e.getFullDescription().c_str(), "An exception has occured!",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_TASKMODAL );
}
```

I don't want to put breakpoint at every catch block. So each time an exception is thrown, a message box show up - I click ok and program close.

What I want is after I click Ok on the message box, Visual studio catch debug in the message box thread and I can see what happens down there in the source code.

Note: I don't know if 'catch debug' is a proper word, when I say 'catch debug', I mean: activate 'Step into' (F11)/'Step over' (F10) feature of Debug mode --> A yellow arrowhead in the margin of a source appears. Maybe the right word is 'break'.

PS: in my situation, I can just use the '[Exception settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/)' (for VS older than 2015, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641102/4608491)) to Break When Throw all C++ Exceptions. Then when any C++ exception is throw, my VS 2015 will break to let me see what happens. Yet, I still want to solve this question, maybe there are situations when it is not exception but just message box - then a skill to break after message box is shown is required.

Comment: With the debugger already attached to the process, you can hit F12 to break into the debugger, then look up the call stack to find where in your code you are.  Or use the "pause" option of the debugger to break execution and look up the call stack.  Or add `ASSERT(FALSE);` after the `MessageBoxA` call.

Comment: Thank you 1201ProgramAlarm, I have tried press F12 but it lead me to the tab: No Symbols Loaded: ntdll.pdb not loaded. Break all won't show any code either.

Comment: Check out the call stack. Work your way down it until you reach your code. Look at the variables used in the call into the stuff you didn't write to see if you can spot the error.

Comment: @user4581301: but the situation here is just message box show, the goal is: try to show the call stack :)

Comment: @123iamking, VS2017 has a new feature called "Using the New Exception Helper" under Tools->Options->Debugging: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/31/using-the-new-exception-helper-in-visual-studio-15-preview/, maybe it could provide you much more useful information during debugging.

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT: Thanks :) VS debug just get better & better :)

Comment: @123iamking, I just add the solution as the answer, if it was helpful, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

You are underestimating the power of `Exception Settings`. It allows you to carefully filter out types of the exceptions that you want to intercept. Open `Exception Settings` window, uncheck "C++ Exceptions" checkbox, select "C++ Exceptions" item (so entire line is highlighted, this will also activate "+" button on toolbar), press "+" button (or use context menu entry) to add `Ogre::Exception` type to the list of exceptions, check `Ogre::Exception` checkbox so only it will be intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you had used MessageBox macro instead of implicitly using MessageBoxA, then you could have done a macro redefine inserting a DebugBreak() afterwards.

I think what I would try at this point is to place a breakpoint at User32!MessageBoxA. This way you get a break before each message box is executed. Then you F10 that call, which will execute the message box, when you press OK it returns back to debugger and you can inspect your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a good solution too (+1). But I'm waiting for Microsoft to develop a new debug method (I hope) that require changing no code but be able to break after click ok on a message box (now, when I click break all, for some situation, it works). If they don't, then create a ShowMessage() function and put breakpoint in this function is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

**Add comment as the solution:**

In VS2017, you could use the new feature called "[Using the New Exception Helper](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/31/using-the-new-exception-helper-in-visual-studio-15-preview/)" under Tools->Options->Debugging. It could provide much more debugging information than previous version like breaking on the Line of Code or faster breaking for Unhandled Exceptions and others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a good solution too (+1). Normally, If I step debug (press F10) from the beginning till the Show-Message-Box code, then after I press Ok for the message box, the debug will break at the code after the Show-Message-Box code. I'm still wait for the new debug method that allow me to do that without have to step debug from the beginning - I don't know if this New Exception Helper can do this (I'm using VS 2015 so I can't confirm this)

Comment: What does "step debug from the beginning"? If you "F11 step into", it would debug your app one step by one step from the beginning? In old VS 2015, it has the Exception setting which could help you catch the Exception, but it couldn't resolve it by itself, you would find the real reason and resolve it manually in your side.

Comment: step debug from the beginning: I mean instead of press F5 to run debug, you press F10 to run debug, and press F10 until you reach the [ShowMessage] code, then close the message box, then Visual Studio take you back to where you leave in the debug.

Comment: @123iamking, VS2017 really has much more new features like "Debugging and Diagnostics" here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-in-visual-studio, but if you have to use the VS2015, I suggest you submit a feature request here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio.

Comment: Thank you Jack Zhai-MSFT :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the execution right after you enter the `catch` block, you want to use a function like `DebugBreak()`. Here is a snippet that you can try:

```
try
{
    throw out_of_range("hello, stackoverflow");
}
catch (exception& e)
{
    // Exection wil stop here.
    // You will see the exception thrown above in the Output console.
    DebugBreak();
}
```

Note that it will also work on the Release builds, not only in Debug.

**EDIT**
If you want exactly that yellow arrow, you could use a *dirty hack* that is ***VERY, VERY BAD PRACTICE***:

```
try
{
    throw out_of_range("hello, stackoverflow");
}
catch (exception& e)
{
    // Now you will get the yellow arrow.
    // From here, you could acces the call stack console that VS provides.
    // By the way, you could have also done that in the previous example.
    int b[1];
    b[1000] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :), debug DebugBreak() is a cool trick, but in my situation, there a countless of block like this, I can't add DebugBreak() through all of these block. Beside, DebugBreak show a green arrow instead of the yellow one.