# How can I debug Boost by viewing the file after precompilation?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I'm getting a very weird bug when defining a test suite with boost like this:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(zerocoin_implementation_tests)
```

The error looks like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
```

Here's the relevant backtrace:

```
#5  0x00007ffff5ce6fe8 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff5ce2875 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff5d7c949 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff70afe15 in boost::unit_test::test_unit::test_unit(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::unit_test::test_unit_type) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.65.1
#9  0x00007ffff70b0456 in boost::unit_test::test_suite::test_suite(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.65.1
#10 0x00007ffff70b0612 in boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar::auto_test_unit_registrar(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::unit_test::decorator::collector&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.65.1
```

From what I can tell, this has to do with Boost trying to create a max length string. I'd like to see exactly what it is doing. What's the best way of expanding boost macros to see the pre-compiled version?

---

### Side Note

Weirdly, if I change the line very slightly to:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(zerocsoin_implementation_tests)
```

I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

And backtrace:

```
#6  0x00007ffff5ce7594 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff70afe15 in boost::unit_test::test_unit::test_unit(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::unit_test::test_unit_type) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.65.1
#8  0x00007ffff70b0456 in boost::unit_test::test_suite::test_suite(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.65.1
#9  0x00007ffff70b0612 in boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar::auto_test_unit_registrar(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::unit_test::decorator::collector&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.65.1
```

The source code for the file (and the rest of the project) can be found here: https://github.com/phoreproject/Phore/blob/segwit/src/test/zerocoin_implementation_tests.cpp

Diff that probably caused the bug: https://github.com/phoreproject/phore/compare/master...segwit#diff-bb4f094cc636d668944ed6af9b72c0d9

Comment: could you post the whole test .cpp file please?

Comment: @skeller updated

Comment: I also added a diff that caused the bug.

Comment: I'm guessing you end up with an unsigned `-1` which overflows, but you should be able to use a debugger to check this kind of thing.

Comment: @o11c sure. my question is: how can I debug boost since most of it is macros.

Comment: @meyer9 the `-g3` option preserves more macro information ... also be sure to use `-O0` (normally, higher optimization levels only hurt debugging a little, but here it matters). Also, try the `-E` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches:

### Exception Breakpoints

Just start the test in the debugger and catch the exception.

In gdb you could do

```
(gdb) catch throw 
Catchpoint 2 (throw)
```

which act like a general breakpoint. Visual Studio has a [Manage Exeptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown) dialog.¹

### Boost Test Breakpoints

For debugging Boost Test I like to set a break at the `test_method` member of the specific test case class I want to break at. E.g. with a test_runner that has a few nested suites like:

```
./test_runner --list_content
import*
    utility*
        xml*
            xml_utilities*
            child_text_test*
            loggable_xml_path_test*
```

And we run these 3 tests like:

```
./test_runner -t import/utility/xml
Running 3 test cases...

*** No errors detected
```

To debug them with gdb I'd do

```
gdb ./test_runner 
start -t import/utility/xml
```

Which stops at main, then I type:

```
break import::utility::xml
```

Auto completion helps, so to get the exact names, you can just pick from the completions:

```
xml
xml::as_element(xmlpp::Node const&)
xml::attr_value(xmlpp::Element const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
xml::attr_value(xmlpp::Node const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
xml::child_text[abi:cxx11](xmlpp::Element const&, char const*)
xml::child_text_test
xml::child_text_test::test_method()
xml::child_text_test_invoker()
xml::child_text_test_registrar62
xml::end_suite94_registrar94
xml::first_child(xmlpp::Element const&, char const*)
xml::get_content[abi:cxx11](xmlpp::Element const&)
xml::get_content[abi:cxx11](xmlpp::Node const*)
xml::is_attr_value(xmlpp::Node const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
xml::loggable_xml_path[abi:cxx11](xmlpp::Node const&)
xml::loggable_xml_path_test
xml::loggable_xml_path_test::test_method()
xml::loggable_xml_path_test_invoker()
xml::loggable_xml_path_test_registrar77
xml::trace_xml(xmlpp::Element const&, LogSource::LogTx)
xml::trace_xml_formatted(xmlpp::Element const&, LogSource::LogTx)
xml::xml_registrar20
xml::xml_utilities
xml::xml_utilities::test_method()
xml::xml_utilities_invoker()
xml::xml_utilities_registrar22
```

Pick the ones named `test_method()`, e.g.

```
break import::utility::xml::child_text_test::test_method() 
Breakpoint 2 at 0x730762: file /path/src/import/utility/xml_tests.cpp, line 62.
```

Now you can `continue` execution and the debugger will automatic pause execution at the start of your unit test.

---

¹ see also

- [Make Visual Studio break on User (std::exception) Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505741/make-visual-studio-break-on-user-stdexception-exceptions)
- [How do I make VC++'s debugger break on exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641042/how-do-i-make-vcs-debugger-break-on-exceptions)